# getting error on using Bootstrap in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a webapp using django, and it was working fine until i included bootstrap nav bar in the html file. after that i am getting the  error on running "python manage.py runserver".

Even on removing the navbar code from html code i am seeing this error.

Thanks in advance.

i am getting the follwing error,

```
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
        handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
        handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
        return get_internal_wsgi_application()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
        return import_string(app_path)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
        module = import_module(module_path)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "D:\Project\webapp\webapp\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
        application = get_wsgi_application()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
        return WSGIHandler()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 135, in __init__
        self.load_middleware()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 37, in load_middleware
        mw_instance = middleware(handler)
    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_module'
```

Comment: Can you share your `MIDDLEWARE` setting? This has likely not (much) to do with bootstrap at all.

Comment: MIDDLEWARE = [
    'allinone.apps.AllinoneConfig',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

Comment: Is `AllinoneConfig` middleware? It looks more like an app config, so then it should be moved to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Is it possible to include relevant parts of your settings file in the question (please [edit] your question).

Comment: yes that was the problem, it got solved., thank you

Comment: Can you answer the question yourself bidyut? And mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: move `'allinone.apps.AllinoneConfig'` from the `MIDDLEWARE` setting to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

The error is located where Django loads middleware. Indeed, the error says:

> ```
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 135, in __init__
>   self.load_middleware()
> ```

It thus means that it constructs a class here. In order to construct middleware, one parameter is passed: the "inner handler".

Your [**`MIDDLEWARE`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware) setting however contains as data:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'allinone.apps.AllinoneConfig',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
    # ...
]
```

Both the name (`AllinoneConfig`), and the parameter name (`app_module`), suggest that `AllinoneConfig` is not a middleware function, but a subclass of [**`AppConfig`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig). You thus should move `'allinone.apps.AllinoneConfig'` to the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps).